# Logistic Regression Outcomes - How to report

Tags: regression, logistic, reporting

I'm reporting my logistic regression results - I have a few, and I wanted to 'double check' and see if I'm getting the verbiage right.

Would anyone be able to advise on the below?
[image]

Response to toffee-nosed hypothesis:

Thanks for the inputs. My responses as follows:

RQ1 – Given that my assertion was that treatment > control, 'rejecting the null' would sound like an indirect answer (and give the reader ‘false hopes’ that the hypothesis was supported, when the rejection was ‘for the opposite tail’), versus a more direct answer such as “I did not find sufficient evidence in support of my hypothesis”. So, to answer your question: the difference is one of simple comprehensibility.

RQ2 – Same as: failure to reject the null hypothesis that all treatment coefficients are equal to 1 (not zero, since this is a logistic reg). Once again, I do not consider the above statement an intuitive response to the hypothesis, hence my tentative plan is to word it as such.

RQ3 – Low power reduces the likelihood that a statistically significant result reflects a true effect. (source: https://www.nature.com/articles/nrn3475). So I say that there’s insufficient evidence because (1) hypothesis got (significantly) contradicted, and (2) there might not be a true effect given the marginal underpowering.

Comment: Some issues to consider:
RQ1. How does "insufficient evidence" differ in your mind from a decision to reject the null hypothesis as suggested by the p-value?
RQ2. Is "no evidnece" the same as failure to reject the null hypothesis as suggested by the p-value?
RQ3. What is the role of power when the decision to reject the null hypothesis is present as suggested by the p-value?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts - I've responded above by modifying my post directly due to length limitations in the comment box.